# How to interpret the words "Doch", "Eines" "Erstellen" and "jeweils"

Tags: meaning

From the movie "The Tin Drum"

In welch begrenzter Welt musste sich der junge Mensch heranbilden. Doch während meine arme Mama und Gretel immer wieder Rasputin lasen, entdeckte ich Goethe. So wuchs ich, wenn nicht äusserlich, so doch innerlich zwischen Rasputin und Goethe hin-und-hergerissen bis ich mir aus beiden Büchern eines erstellte, so das der dämonischen Seite jeweils eine erleuchtete folgte...

Comment: Can't you just look them up online? I'd expect Google Translate to do pretty well translating those words. If you really want to *interpret* them, you need to elaborate since interpretation is a versatile subject.

Comment: *Doch während* → here: *in contrary*. It should be no problem to look up the correct meaning for the others in some dictionary.

Comment: Did you use a dictionary? What exactly is still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

For those words that are more difficult to look up in a dictionary because of multitude or complexity of meaning:

> Doch...

means here something like *contrasting to that*, *contrasting to what was said before*.

> ... bis ich mir aus beiden Büchern eines erstellte...

is the same as *aus beiden Büchern **ein einziges** erstellte* (English e.g. *until in my mind both books got totally mixed up*).